# Is enthalpy only defined for systems which exchange heat at constant pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics

Clearly, in the derivation of enthalpy we have assumed that constant pressure is acting on the system. So, doesn't this mean that enthalpy is only defined for systems which are at isobaric condition? I am so confused. Following is the derivation of enthalpy function (clearly we have assumed pressure to be constant) :

[image: Enthalpy]

Answer (score 1):

Enthapy is defined as
$$
  H \equiv U + PV
$$

This definition is a mathematical equality. It is valid even if the pressure is not constant.

But it is more useful under isobaric condition. Because the varibale of the enthalphy is $P$, $S$, $N$:

$$
  d H = T dS + V dP + \mu dN.
$$

$dP= 0$ under isobaric condition.

On the other hand, if we use the internal energy $U= U(S, V, N)$
$$
  dU = T dS - P dV + \mu DN.
$$
This relation is hard to apply for a condition $dP=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Enthalpy is an intrinsic physical property of the material comprising the system, rather than something associated with any specific kind of process.  It is determined by the thermodynamic equilibrium state that the material is in, and is defined in terms of the internal energy U, the pressure P, and the volume V of the material by $H\equiv U+PV$.

Between two thermodynamic equilibrium states of the material, the change in enthalpy does not have to take place at constant temperature, pressure, or anything else.  For example, if we look at the change in enthalpy of a pure incompressible liquid at constant temperature between two pressures, we find that it is given $\Delta H=V\Delta P$.  We know that enthalpy is an intrinsic physical property of materials because its values are presented in published tables for various materials, such as water "steam tables," as functions of temperature, pressure, and state of aggregation (liquid and vapor).  The values in these tables can be used to analyze quantitatively specific processes that the material is subjected to.